# passive with wh-

Tags: grammar, meaning, future-tense, to-infinitive, wh-questions

when passive is used, it is mandatory to use be verb.

Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: How do you want to use the phrase 'what to be done'? We can't tell you how to 'fix it' if we don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for commenting on my post! I am studying the sentences whether they are correct or not. By the way, I wondered 'what to be done' can be used as 'what to do' is commonly used. Does it make sense?

Comment: Your example is SYNTACTICALLY INVALID, because the "embedded question" doesn't contain a verb. You have to say *I asked what **was** to be done.* Or feasibly *I asked what **Is** to be done*, but that's unlikely except in a true reported speech context: *"What is to be done?", I asked*.

Comment: You're right that people do say _What to do?_ I think you need to regard this as an idiom. There are a few other verbs which can substitute (_What to wear?_ comes to mind), but most verbs won't work. I think it is best analysed as having an unspoken _I wonder_ before it. That both makes the syntax normal, and fits the context in which it is usually used.

Answer (score 1):

Now you have supplied a proper sentence, I can tell you that, no, you can't use *what to be done* in the same way.

I asked what to do = what *I should do* (an active verb).

*To be done* is passive, so you need to add *was*.

I asked what was to be done = what action needed to be taken.

Comment: Julie - You edited your question to make it clearer what you were asking (which was good), but now you have edited it again, removing the question and expressing thanks. _Please don't do that!_ You should leave the question so that readers of the forum know what the conversation was about. Any thanks for answers should be in comments.

Comment: Ohh, Sorry! I should have kept that in my mind,,, it is my mistake. I promise you not to do it again...